# Centering absolute img in absolute div responsively, feels like I tried everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I've been browsing for hours looking for a solution, but none of them work for me.

I have an absolutely positioned div (#hero-img) acting as a background container with an img in it (using a real background is not an option, as I'm using a jQuery cycle with fading).

Here's what I've finally settled on that *almost* works:

html:

```
<div id="hero-img">
    <img src="img/heros/hero-img.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hero-img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#hero-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

if( w / h < 1650 / 1050 ) {
    $('#hero-img img').css("height", "100%");
    $('#hero-img img').css("width", "auto");
}
else {
    $('#hero-img img').css("width", "100%");
    $('#hero-img img').css("height", "auto");
}
```

This seems to work when the window is *wide* but not when mobile sized.

You can check it out at kylebashour.com/carlex to see what I mean.

I tried the 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: (half of image width);
but it pushes it left too far at some sizes (I think because the width is auto perhaps..)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on how you want it to function. Do you want the image to go off the edges of the screen (crop) when the window is smaller? Or do you want the image to shrink to fit the window?

Comment: It should crop on the edges, but be centered both horiz/vert. I really want it to behave like background: cover center center, but can't use a background unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for horizontal centering, try this in your `img` **CSS** code:

```
#hero-img img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```

Also if you want vertical and horizontal centering, try this:

```
#hero-img img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: OH MY GOSH you're so awesome! It seems to work perfectly. Why doesn't margin-left work? and this does?

Comment: Nice and clean! Note that CSS3 translations are [not supported in IE<9](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Comment: Thanks showdev, that much support is fine with me though.